# How to display students’ report Cards (with Ca and exam Scores) in RDLC report in Asp.Net using vb.net

Tags: report, rdlc

I am developing a School Management Application that takes in the CA and Exam Scores of students into the database to be displayed in the report card of each student.
I created a score table and populated it accordingly
I also created a report to display students’ report card but it shows only one subject per student, the rest of the subjects did not show. Each student offers 16 subjects.
I used "Table" in RDLC report viewer. Though, it displayed all the students and their exam scores in the table view. When I went into Row Group property, I clicked “Between each instance of a group”, it displace only the first subject only. But I want it to display like this for each student:

```
Surname:    xxxxx   Firstname:  xxxxx   Othername:  xxxxx       Sex:x   DOB:xx/xx/xxxx
Class: xxxxx    Term: xxxxx Session: xxxxxxx
SUBJECT CA  EXAM    TOTALSCORE
English     20  50  70
Math        21  52  73
```

Computer St 25  49  74 
And so on.
This is my Table. The table name is “Score”
My Dataset query is this:

```
SELECT        AdmNo, Surname, Firstname, Othername, Sex, DOB, Class, Term, Session, Subject, CA, Exam, TotalScore, 
FROM            Score
WHERE        (Class = @Class) AND (Term = @Term) AND (Session = @Session)
GROUP BY Subject, AdmNo, Surname, Firstname, Othername, Sex, DOB, Class, Term, Session, Subject, CA, Exam, TotalScore
ORDER BY AdmNo
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I understood from your question you haven't created any group. First to get report like you mentions you have to group according to the Name(Main group). Then by class ,subject etc as sub groups.

For creating a group

1. go to corresponding rdlc
2. in bottom you will find Column Group click on down arrow
3. click Advanced options Now you will see more static in Row group
4. click on the 1st one it will probably select the Sur name so click Group properties
5. In general Add then one Group on field will come in that give the Parameters like SurName
6. for creating sub group again do the same

And remove all those things like page break between each instance of group etc

Comment: Thanks I wl try it